# Mount all passed in secrets in the Dockerfile RUN command

Tags: docker

Suppose I have a Dockerfile where I use a secret passed in, like so:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=ENV_VAR_ON_BUILD_MACHINE cat /run/secrets/ENV_VAR_ON_BUILD_MACHINE
```

Now if I build my docker file like so:

```
docker build --secret id=ENV_VAR_ON_BUILD_MACHINE --progress=plain --no-cache -t test .
```

I can see the output matching the value of `ENV_VAR_ON_BUILD_MACHINE` on my machine.

How can I read ALL of the passed in secrets INSIDE dockerfile e.g. sth like

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=*
```

This is a part of a larger setup where I want to build a frontend app with `vite` using GCP CloudBuild so I want to pass my GSM values into the build and then to vite command so that their values are baked into my `dist`.